# Go through all the arguments of a va_list without knowing in advance how many variable arguments it is composed of

Tags: c, variadic-functions

My question is: Is there a way to go through all the arguments of a va_list without knowing a priori how many variable arguments it is composed of? On the web I found examples where the number of the ellipse's arguments was passed as the first argument and therefore, using a for loop, it was easy to navigate the elements. I wish my function was implicit.

Comment: If you can pass a sentinel value then you don't need a format string or size to be passed in.  What parameters do you want to pass to your function?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah For example, if I wanted to pass a series of strings to the function, I would not necessarily specify how many they are, I would simply like to pass them, and the function understood by itself how many there are.

Comment: The variadic function mechanism in C does not provide any information about how many arguments are present or what their types are.  You must supply that information yourself.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a sentinel value like `(char*)0` to denote the end (similar to C's null-terminated strings) but that's explicit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to go through all the arguments of a va_list without knowing a priori how many variable arguments it is composed of?

No, there is not. The count (and type) of arguments has to be known, either use a sentinel value or pass a variable or have the count of arguments depend on other argument (I mean, like `printf`). The information about count of arguments is not stored anywhere - if that information is needed for your algorithm, you have to pass it yourself.

You can write macros that will overload on number of arguments and pass the argument count as parameter. Or for a sentinel approach you can also write a macro that will pass `NULL` and if you are using gcc, there is a [gcc `attribute(sentinel)` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) which will spawn warning is the sentinel `NULL` is missing.

Comment: Pedantic note: Passing `NULL` as a sentinel for a list of `char *` is iffy as `NULL` may be an integer 0 of some type and not a _pointer_.  As the size and type may differ from the receiving functions use of `va_arg(va_list ap, char *);`, UB results.  Better to use [`(char *)NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768930/go-through-all-the-arguments-of-a-va-list-without-knowing-in-advance-how-many-va#comment111002012_62768930).